# How to find all matching objects in an image with SIFT

Tags: python, c#, c++, opencv, computer-vision

I have a picture of a diamond card, and a small picture of one diamond, I'm trying to find all the diamonds in the big picture

Below are the pictures:

[image]

[image]

Below is the experimental code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using OpenCvSharp;
using OpenCvSharp.Features2D;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var src = new Mat("8_diamonds.png");
            var templ = new Mat("diamonds_template.png");
            var dst = new Mat();
            SiftDetector(src, templ, dst, 0, 3, 0.04, 10, 0.6, 1.75);
            Cv2.ImShow("dst", dst);
            Cv2.ImShow("src", src);
            Cv2.ImShow("templ", templ);
            Cv2.WaitKey();
        }

        private static Scalar[] _Scalars = new[]
        {
            new Scalar(255, 0, 0),
            new Scalar(0, 255, 0),
            new Scalar(0, 0, 255),
            new Scalar(255, 255, 0),
            new Scalar(0, 255, 255),
            new Scalar(255, 0, 255),
        };

        public static void SiftDetector(Mat src, Mat templ, Mat dst,
            int nFeatures = 0,
            int nOctaveLayers = 3,
            double contrastThreshold = 0.04,
            double edgeThreshold = 10,
            double sigma = 1.6,
            double ratio_thresh = 0.75)
        {
            var detector = SIFT.Create(nFeatures, nOctaveLayers, contrastThreshold, edgeThreshold, sigma);
            var descriptors_templ = new Mat();
            var descriptors_src = new Mat();
            detector.DetectAndCompute(templ, null, out var keypoints_templ, descriptors_templ);
            detector.DetectAndCompute(src, null, out var keypoints_src, descriptors_src);

            var matcher = new FlannBasedMatcher();

            src.CopyTo(dst);
            if (dst.Channels() == 1)
            {
                Cv2.CvtColor(dst, dst, ColorConversionCodes.GRAY2BGR);
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                var knn_matches = matcher.KnnMatch(descriptors_templ, descriptors_src, 2);

                //-- Filter matches using the Lowe's ratio test            
                var good_matches = new List<DMatch>();
                for (var i = 0; i < knn_matches.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (knn_matches[i][0].Distance < ratio_thresh * knn_matches[i][1].Distance)
                    {
                        good_matches.Add(knn_matches[i][0]);
                    }
                }

                if (good_matches.Count < 4)
                {
                    break;
                }

                var dstPts = new List<Point2d>();
                var srcPts = new List<Point2d>();
                for (var i = 0; i < good_matches.Count; i++)
                {
                    dstPts.Add(keypoints_templ[good_matches[i].QueryIdx].Pt.ToPoint2d());
                    srcPts.Add(keypoints_src[good_matches[i].TrainIdx].Pt.ToPoint2d());
                }

                Mat H = Cv2.FindHomography(dstPts, srcPts, HomographyMethods.Ransac);

                if (H.Cols != 0)
                {
                    var obj_corners = new Point2d[4];
                    obj_corners[0] = new Point2d(0, 0);
                    obj_corners[1] = new Point2d(templ.Cols, 0);
                    obj_corners[2] = new Point2d(templ.Cols, templ.Rows);
                    obj_corners[3] = new Point2d(0, templ.Rows);
                    var scene_corners = Cv2.PerspectiveTransform(obj_corners, H);

                    var drawingPoints = scene_corners.Select(p => (Point)p).ToArray();
                    Cv2.Polylines(dst, new[] { drawingPoints }, true, Scalar.Lime, 4);
                }

                foreach (var match in srcPts)
                {
                    dst.Circle(match.ToPoint(), 5, _Scalars[j % _Scalars.Length], 2);
                }

                var toRemove = good_matches.Select(p => p.TrainIdx).Distinct().ToList();

                foreach (var row in toRemove)
                {
                    descriptors_src.Row(row).SetTo(new Scalar(float.MaxValue, float.MaxValue, float.MaxValue));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static class Extentions
    {
        public static Point2d ToPoint2d(this Point2f point2F)
        {
            return new Point2d(point2F.X, point2F.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

In this code I search for matches, paint around the found object, then delete the matches and search again.

The result is:

[image]

The question is how do I find all the diamonds and not just the first one?

`SIFT` is not required, `SURF` or any similar algorithm is also possible.

An answer in **Python** or **C++** would also be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does it have to be sift or surf? I did something kind of similar when I was doing an intro computer vision course in school to find the location of notes on a sheet of music. In this case the templates and images I was matching against were always in the same rotation. I used multiple rounds of template matching while scaling the template image size. The scale with the best matches was used as the result. https://github.com/cal-pratt/SheetVision/blob/master/best_fit.py

Comment: `SIFT` and its friends, is not sensitive to rotation, scale and does not compare pixels but features, so it is better than naive pattern matching.

Comment: @googledev - Sure, sift is a lot rotation and scale invariant, but you have more than one object which will match with your diamond template. I am wondering what if you just use morphological operation to filter regions that are good individual candidate for diamond template. First find card region using sift matches with good score and then you know where your card is, roughly. Next you can do some thresholding to find where the red areas and white areas are and finally you can apply connected component to find all red diamonds.

Comment: The tricky part of your attempted approach is that the template can match different diamonds at the same time. For example, the top half of the template could match the first diamond, while the bottom half matches the second diamond with the same score (or it could even be the first diamond with a 180 degree rotation). In such a situation, FindHomography would oddly stretch the template to fit both. You can visualize this behavior by filling the top half of the card with white (i.e., removing the easy diamonds).

Comment: @ken Maybe you can use `pointPolygonTest` to differentiate between key points inside the Lime polygon and those outside.

Comment: It may help suppress false positives, but it will not help improve true positives (that is the problem). I think manually filtering the matching results, e.g. by clustering, would work. However, any solution will have a negative impact on robustness. So I suggest switching to object detection, which is better suited to the task.

Comment: You can remove the one you encounter and resend the new image... but yeah not optimal solution at all.

Comment: Just an opinion. You could also have a look at instance segmentation under machine learning. It could provide you an alternative solution without using SIFT/SURF methods. ML methods for instance segmentation.

Answer (score 0):

The basic solution to the problem you're posing is in 10-15 lines:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

card = cv2.imread('rIQyp.png')
card_gray = cv2.cvtColor(card, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.imread('zzBUd.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

cv2.namedWindow("card", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
res = cv2.matchTemplate(card_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)

for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(card, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)
    
while cv2.getWindowProperty('card', 0) >= 0:
    cv2.waitKey(10)
    cv2.imshow("card", card)
```

[image: result]

It works because this problem in the nutshell is exactly what the algorithm name is: you need to find regions of in a given imagery('matches') which should within euclidian transforms be fitting, "matching" - to a set standard image('template'). I.e. template matching.

There are many varieties of template matching, which primarily deal with concerns of mentioned transforms and lighting. If you don't want to get deep into that for any reason you can always deal with those yourself: for example in the case of cards you can apply Hough transform to get all the cards, even partly occluded, transform them to proper rectangle pieces given the proportions you already know and do naive template matching which you can completely write yourself and you get exactly all matches that present in general case.

This is what I would actually do in production for real application such as card counting from a camera feed.
If a problem like that becomes too ad-hoc'y - just train a basic CNN which  nowadays is also 10-30 lines of code.

Comment: The question is how to find with `SURF` or `SIFT` and the like, and not with `matchTemplate`, since the solution has to be applied to other cases and not necessarily to the card in the picture, where `matchTemplate` will not help and only `SIFT` and `SURF` will help, the only problem is that you have to **find all instances** and not just the first one.
The main question is how to **find all the objects** with `SURF` or `SIFT` and similar.

Comment: If you take a look at the solution - it does find all the instances *exactly*. Morever if you can a second image or simply two thresholds to differentiate between the small and large templates. "where matchTemplate will not help and only SIFT and SURF will help" - this is not the question asked. Please ask the question with those "other cases".

Comment: I think the whole issue here is misunderstanding of the what the SIFT does and what the template matching does. SIFT is used in category of problems which are *feature detection*, it literally describes the features. Wikipedia gives out the science taxonomy pretty neat:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform
You only use feature detection to detect or match object when they are changed and complex. For example, cathedral from different ages, weather, renovation ..when building *changed*. You have here a simple ethalon that is not changed in target image

Comment: You have actually accomplished the SIFT within your answer already! And you showed the result for it you can see the number of features it found right in your image! This is a bad input - the diamond is very simple object and really doesn't have a lot of good features so you have same features from card border etc, - though for whatever it worth - it is the best you can do with it. Now you can collect the features, adjust the tresholds to according number - so that all diamonds will match and voila! You solved the problem as much as it can be solved with SIFT part.